# Java expression: Not allow single quote in middle or Allow single quote with double back slash

Tags: java, regex

**The format I want to validate**

1. Start with single quote (after left trim)
2. End with single quote (after right trim)
3. In the middle: No single quote allowed OR allow it but it must be escaped using double back slash

**Samples**

```
'abc' --> valid
'abc\\'def' --> valid
'abc'def' --> invalid
```

**What I tried**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\s*\\'[^']+\\'\\s*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);

    System.out.println(pat.matcher("'abc'").matches());  // Out: true
    System.out.println(pat.matcher("'abc\\'def'").matches()); //Out: false, expected true
    System.out.println(pat.matcher("'abc'def'").matches()); // out false
}
```

**I am having issue with this rule:**

```
allow a single quote in middle but it must be escaped by \\
```

Any helps? Thanks!

Comment: `final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\s*'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'\\s*");`

Comment: `"'abc\\'def'"` is the string `'abc\'def'`, *not* the string `'abc\\'def'`.

Comment: @Andreas: What you say is clear as day. OP needs to also match escaped quotes in between the first and last single quotes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew What I'm saying is that the question text and the question code is not consistent. Text says that the actual *string* must have *double* backslash before single quote. Code says that Java *literal* must have double backslash, which means that the *string* must have *single* backslash. The question is unclear.

Comment: the string literal does have two backslashes. The expected behavior and code to test are provided and are clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
final Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\s*'[^'\\\\]*(?:\\\\.[^'\\\\]*)*'\\s*");
```

See the [Java demo](http://ideone.com/4yhknZ).

*Details*:

- `\s*` -  0+ whitespaces
- `'` - a single quote
- `[^'\\]*` - 0+ chars other than `'` and `\`
- `(?:\\.[^'\\]*)*` - zero or more sequences of

  - `\\.` - any escape char other than linebreak char (add `Pattern.DOTALL` to match any char incl. newlines)
  - `[^'\\]*`- 0+ chars other than `'` and `\`
- `'`  - a single quote
- `\s*` - 0+ whitespaces

Comment: `"'abc\\'def'"` is the string `'abc\'def'`, with only one backslash, and your code accepts it. Should only accept if `'` is preceded by *double* backslash. True test would likely have to be that `'` must be preceded by an *even* number of backslashes.

Comment: @Andreas: Look - `System.out.println(pat.matcher("'abc\\'def'").matches()); //Out: false, expected true` - there is only 1 *literal*  backslash before the single quote. If you look at the online code demo, it returns the expected value (true).

Answer (score 1):

Try this ("pure" regex form for readability; needs escaping in a Java string):

```
\s*\'([^'\\]|\\')*\'\s*
```

Inside the string, we accept an arbitrary number of occurrences of either characters that are not `'` or `\`, or precisely the escape sequence `\'`. Note that this will disallow the backslash in front of other characters, which is how escape characters generally work. (I also suggest using `*` rater than `+` in order to allow for empty strings.)